# "illegal thread-local reference to regular symbol" error on a TLS variable

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, clang, thread-local-storage

I have a strange issue that occurs during linking.

I have a header file that contains the following definition `foo.hpp`:

```
struct Foo { static __thread int x; }
```

And a source file which references that variable `plugin.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.hpp"
void bar() { int y = Foo::x; }
```

It compiles fine with:

```
$CXX -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -fPIC -o plugin.cpp.o -c plugin.cpp
```

But when I try to link as a dynamic library:

```
$CXX -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -dynamiclib -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -o libext.dylib ext.cpp.o
```

I get:

> ld: illegal thread local variable reference to regular symbol
>   __ZN3Foo1xE for architecture x86_64

However the llvm bytecode implies that the compiler is correctly seeing `Foo::x` as a TLS variable.

```
$CXX -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -fvisibility=hidden -fPIC -S -emit-llvm -o -
... omitted
@_ZN3Foo1xE = external thread_local global i32
... omitted
; Function Attrs: nounwind ssp uwtable
define hidden void @_Z3barv() #0 {
  %y = alloca i32, align 4
  %1 = load i32* @_ZN3Foo1xE, align 4
  store i32 %1, i32* %y, align 4
  ret void
}
```

What could be causing this linker issue, and is there a workaround? I can't seem to find any bug reports related to this.

Notes:

- This is purely using the Apple LLVM 7.0.0
- I have no problems linking using either gcc 5 or gcc 4.9.3 on OS X

**EDIT**
The same problem exists when referencing a global (instead of static class) variable.

When I use `thread_local` in place of `__thread`, this works fine, however `thread_local` does not work with the version of LLVM that ships with Xcode.

Comment: What happens if you make `Foo::x` a global variable instead?  If that works you could leave it global, or have it local (static or anonymous namespace) to foo.cpp with a static getter function in `Foo`.  I'm just guessing; maybe the compiler has a problem with static __thread member variables.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: I should have put that in the question. Using a global variable yields the exact same problem. Of course, to make the use case equivalent, the declaration is `extern __thread int my_global;`

Comment: You only declared the x variable, show us the definition for it.  Dollars to donuts, you forgot __thread in the definition.  Or you forgot it completely and got a lousy linker diagnostic.

Comment: The definition occurs in a completely different translation unit, hence why the definition is not included. It should not matter when building a dynamic library. And as I mentioned in the question, it works fine using `thread_local` in clang 7

Comment: 'thread_local' requires proper initialization in all contexts, including correctly calling constructors within a DLL. The precursor versions of thread-local storage usually (all?) have some deficit with respect to `thread_local`. If I had to guess, I'd say that `__thread` is one of these precursor versions and does not actually work in a DLL context. If this is the case, the error message is actually telling you that the tool chain doesn't support your usage.

Comment: Quoting from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2659.htm  "At present, all implementations of thread-local storage do not support dynamic initalization (and presumably non-trivial destructors). There was mild consensus at the Mont Treblant meeting to support dynamic initialization of function-local, thread-local variables. The intialization of such variables is already guarded and synchronous, so new technology is not required. [...]

Comment: [...]  On the other hand, the implementation for dynamic initialization of namespace-scope variables is much more difficult, and may require additional linker and operating system support. There was no consensus to support dynamic initialization of namespace-scope variables at that time. However, interviews with prospective users indicated a firm desire for full dynamic initialization of thread storage duration variables. The programmers simply did not want to partition their types this way. "

Comment: Also, that same document has a section specifically addressing the implementation realities of dynamic linking.

Comment: @eh9, It is my understanding that `__thread` variables must be statically initialized (indeed, the compiler complains if a `constexpr` constructor is not used in the initialization of `__thread` variables for aggregate types). To give more background, the actual use case is that the definition of the variable is in a separately compiled binary and accessed by plugins (which see the declaration in a header file, as in the question). It does not seem to matter if the variables are globally declared `extern`s or namespaced to a class, and as I stated previously, the linking works fine using gcc.

Comment: @eh9 this may just be a case of LLVM support of `__thread` being less extensive than gcc's :/ Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any documentation that addresses this discrepancy.

Comment: @JoelCornett Yes, `__thread` in LLVM isn't the same as `__thread` in GCC; neither is standard.

Answer (score 1):

Apples executable file format (MACH-O I believe) does not allow for Thread local storage. Its a pain in the ass. You have to create space in the threading library's memory allocation and hide the thread local variables in there. Its very very obscure.

Comment: A link that should describe this.   https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/topic/498638